# x86 Asm Insertion sort

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, insertion-sort

I've tried reading about this all over the internet but here it is my problem. I am given a string of doublewords.

I have to order in decreasing order the string of the low words (least significant) from these doublewords. The high words remain unchanged. 
For ex: strin DD 12345678h 1256ABCDh, 12AB4344h 
the result would be 1234ABCDh, 12565678h, 12AB4344h.

Now I tried my best writting some code but it's not working properly, my insertion procedure. If you could take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be greatful.
I tried running it in td mode but I just can't figure out.

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
    s dd 12345678h, 1256ABCDh, 12AB4344h
    ls equ ($-s)/4  ;this is supposed to be the length of my source string
    d dd ls dup (?) ;this is my destination string
    aux dw ?
    aux2 dw ?
data ends

code segment
insert proc
    push di ;here I use the stack to get more free registers
    push cx
    cmp di, offset d ;if di=offset d it means that I didn't store any number yet
    je addPrim 
    std ;we plan on working form right to left on the string for the next part
    mov cx, di
    sub cx, offset d ;here I find out with how many words I have to compare the word from AX
    dec di
    dec di ;since I work with doublewords, for some reason I thought I should decrease di
    dec di ;3 times but here my procedure gets fuzzy and doesn't work properly anymore
    repeta1: ;this repeat is supposed to compare the word from AX with the rest of the least 
        scasw ;significant words from es:di
        jge DIplus2 ;if my number from AX is bigger or equal than what's in es:di, I increment
 ;di twice and store it
        mov bx, word ptr es:[di+1] ;this part is supposed to interchange words but it's not
 ;working how I planned so I don't know how to change it
        mov word ptr es:[di+2], bx
        loop repeta1

    jmp DIplus1

    DIplus2:
        inc di

    DIplus1:
        inc di

    addPrim: ;this label  just adds the first word in the destination string
        stosw

    pop cx
    pop di
    inc di
    inc di
    cld
    ret 
    insert endp

start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov si, offset s
    mov di, offset d
    mov cx, ls ; store in cx the length of the strings
    jcxz exit

repeta:
    lodsw ;because of little endian, my first word will be my least significant word in the 
;in the doubleword so right after it is moved in ax, i apply the procedure insert
    call insert
    lodsw ;here it moves in ax my most significan word in the dd, so i auto store it 
    stosw ;in my destination string 
    loop repeta

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls equ ($-s)/4  ;this is supposed to be the length of my source string
```

This actually calculates the number of elements.

```
mov cx, di
sub cx, offset d ;here I find out with how many words ...
```

At the second invocation of your insert proc this will set CX=4 which is too big given a list of only 3 values. I suggest you divide CX by 4.

```
dec di
dec di ;since I work with doublewords...
dec di ;3 times but here my procedure gets fuzzy
```

This is certainly wrong. SCASW indicates you either decrement by 4 or not decrement at all!

```
mov bx, word ptr es:[di+1] ;this part is supposed to interchange words...
mov word ptr es:[di+2], bx
```

This cannot work since the offsets are only 1 byte apart!

```
jmp DIplus1
```

This yields an single increment of DI and thus an error because you want to store a word at that spot.

Comment: Ooo thank you! I fixed it and it's working properly now ^_^ yea I used to work with scasw before but I changed it to cmp and then then DI increments weren't needed anymore. Thanks a lot.